# Converting shapefile to KML with correct coordinate system

Tags: shapefile, google-maps, kml

I am working on this [SHP file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21125338/dc_simp_05.shp), containing geographical district of Hong Kong. I would like to export this to KML and export it to Google Map for overlay.

After I converted it to KML in QGIS (just save as kml format) and opened it in Google Map, it seems the coordinate is out of the entire map world region.

Is there any conversion I need to do from ESRI SHP coordinate system to Google Map compatible coordinate system?

Comment: The final command I ran:

`ogr2ogr -s_srs EPSG:2326 -t_srs EPSG:4326 -f "KML" ~/output.kml ~/input.shp`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For such conversion I often use the free and opensource tool [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html)

An easy to use command line. A [cheatsheet](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=ogr_cheatsheet) with must common command from Boston GIS

It would be something like: `ogr2ogr "KML" output_filename.kml input_filename.shp`

With this tool you can also set the coordinate system.

Comment: KML only supports WGS 84 system

Answer (score 2):

Yes off course you need to change the coordinate system. I think you are working with local projected coordinate system. Google KML support Global WGS84. Please convert your coordinate system to WGS84 and then try again to convert the ESRI shp file to KML. If you have access to ArcGIS data interoperability then you can easily convert also.